# How to disconnect phone call in flutter?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I made app that call automatically on given number, code below. Now I want to disconnect that call for after f.g 10 sec. It is possible if yes how to do it?

```
    android_intent.Intent()
      ..setAction(android_action.Action.ACTION_CALL)
      ..setData(Uri(scheme: "tel", path: _controllerPhone.text))
      ..startActivity().catchError((e) => print(e));
```

Comment: did you manage to do it? any help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the call application is a different application than your application, you can not intervene. Of course, you could do this very easily if you were making a call directly in your application.

Comment: Ok, could you say or give a link to how to do this?

Comment: Making a calling app will take time. You can take a look at this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged